# JMenu submenu items not displayed properly

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I'm tyring to add 2 `JRadioButtonMenuItem`s as sub menu items to a `JMenuItem`, but the sub menu items are not getting displayed correctly.

This the code I have tried so far

```
 private void setupEditMenu() {

    editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");

    // some code..

    tabSpaceMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Tab Length");
    editMenu.add(tabSpaceMenuItem);

    ButtonGroup tabSpaceButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JMenuItem fourSpacedTabMenuItem, eightSpacedTabMenuItem;

    fourSpacedTabMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("4 spaces");
    fourSpacedTabMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            editor.setTabSize(4);
        }
    });
    tabSpaceButtonGroup.add(fourSpacedTabMenuItem);
    tabSpaceMenuItem.add(fourSpacedTabMenuItem);

    eightSpacedTabMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("8 spaces");
    eightSpacedTabMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            editor.setTabSize(8);
        }
    });
    tabSpaceButtonGroup.add(eightSpacedTabMenuItem);
    tabSpaceMenuItem.add(eightSpacedTabMenuItem);

    if(editor.getTabSize() == 4)
        fourSpacedTabMenuItem.setSelected(true);
    if(editor.getTabSize() == 8) {
        eightSpacedTabMenuItem.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Current Output
[image]

Expected:

```
Edit
 |-Find
 |-Font
 |-Tab Length
    |- 4 spaces
    |- 8 spaces
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JMenuItem` isn't a container for other `JMenuItem`s.  Instead, change `tabSpaceMenuItem` to `JMenu` instead...

```
tabSpaceMenuItem = new JMenu("Tab Length");
```

[image: Submenu Items]

Comment: My bad, I wonder how I missed that, BTW, Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to the forest, watch out for the trees ;)